# Get Deferred from dbpool.runQuery instead of data with Twisted and Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, twisted, deferred

I am trying to get some data from Oracle, using Twisted and runQuery and keep getting Deferred instead of actual data.
How can this be solved?
Some code (I excluded some unnecessary parts, but the idea should be clear):

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twisted.internet import defer
import service_config

ORACLE_DSN = service_config.oracle_dsn
ORACLE_USER = service_config.oracle_user
ORACLE_PASSWORD = service_config.oracle_password
dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('cx_Oracle',
    user=ORACLE_USER,
    password=ORACLE_PASSWORD,
    dsn=ORACLE_DSN, port='49161')

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def ask_db():
    data = yield dbpool.runQuery("SELECT * FROM customer")

a = ask_db()
print(a)
```

I got reactor running in other module, if that is important.
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
With help of @notorious.no got working code, returning data instead of Deferred with Python 3.5:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def ask_db(request):
    data = yield dbpool.runQuery(request)

    return defer.returnValue(data)
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from your ask_db function.. If you change your print(a) to a print(data) inside ask_db, what happens then?

Comment: Do you mean     def ask_db():
    data = yield dbpool.runQuery("SELECT * FROM customer")     print(data)?  If yes, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a Deferred because you're calling an `inlineCallback` which always returns a Deferred. You're also misinterpreting what `yield` does. It doesn't actually return a value from an `inlinceCallback` it just wait's for a result. Use `defer.returnValue()` to return a value (you can use a simple `return` if you're using Python 3.4+). This is what your code should look like:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
#...

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def ask_db():
    data = yield dbpool.runQuery("SELECT * FROM customer")
    defer.returnValue(data)    # actually return a value

a = ask_db()    # this returns a Deferred so add callbacks!
a.addCallback(print)    # add a useful callback to processes query list
reactor.run()
```

The difference between what you had previously and this answer is that a callback is added so when the `runQuery()` returns with a value, the callback is executed and `ask_db()` actually returns a value you care about.

## References

- [Database Usage with Klein/Twisted](https://notoriousno.blogspot.com/2016/08/twisted-klein-database-usage.html)

Comment: Thank you!
I used defer.returnValue(data) and a.addCallback(some other func) but still the same result. Even more - 'some other func' from addCallback doesn't even start, so to me it looks like yield stays in Deferred and doesn't change to data or failure.
Could it be in case ConnectionPool doesn't really connect to DB? Or it has to return some ConnectionError?
I forgot to mention, I use Python 3.5.
And I have reactor running in another module, so is it necessary to add reactor.run() into this module?

Comment: When I said "I used defer.returnValue(data) and a.addCallback(some other func) but still the same result." I meant I used it before posting this question.
And I tried to use it now also. And still Deferred as a result.

Comment: Are you doing ``print(a)`` or ``print(ask_db())``? Because that won't give the results of the query, that will print the Deferred object. Not sure why callbacks don't start though, what happens when you use the synchronous syntax? What happens when you run ``cx_Oracle.connect(user, pswd, dsn, port)``?

Comment: Looks like your solution works, but as I have lots of sync logic around ask_bd() those functions seem to be the problem. I can tell later after I rewrite all the stuff. Thank you!
I found minor mistake with ConnectionPool args also. There have to be "IP:port" in dsn, not "port=" separately.

Comment: Thank you @notorious.no, with your help got working code!